# Dynamically creating syncfusion schedule along with grid and textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, syncfusion

im trying to create a SfSchedule dynamically. Creating the Sf Schedule was easy but now i need to add grid and textboxes to recreate it as it is in the .xaml

How to be able to create DataTemplate dynamically and adding grid and textboxes dynamically too?

I have the code within a .xaml that is working correctly but i want to create it dynamically. What i did so far is to use the SfSchedule WeekSchedule = new SfSchedule(); and assign values to its properties but now i need to create the SfSchedule.AppointmentTemplate and DataTemplate dynamically, this is where im trying with DataTemplate Data = new DataTemplate(); but it is not letting me add any of the grid, rectangle or textboxes.

```
<syncfusion:SfSchedule ScheduleType="Month" Name="schedule"  >
   <syncfusion:SfSchedule.AppointmentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>               
            <Rectangle Fill="White" Stroke="Black" 
              StrokeThickness="3"></Rectangle>         
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding AppointmentBackground}"  
              Width="10" ></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    FontSize="15" 
                    Text="{Binding Subject}" 
                    Foreground="{Binding AppointmentBackground}" 
                    FontStyle="Normal"></TextBlock>
              </StackPanel>
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
     </syncfusion:SfSchedule.AppointmentTemplate>
</syncfusion:SfSchedule>
```

C#

```
SfSchedule WeekSchedule = new SfSchedule();
WeekSchedule.HeaderDateFormat = "dddd dd";

DataTemplate DataTemp = new DataTemplate();

Grid firstGrid = new Grid();
DataTemp.Add(firstGrid); //This is what actually dont work, the datatemplate doesnt allow add

Rectange r1 = new Rectange();
r1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
r1.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
r1.StrokeThickness = 3;
DataTemp.Add(r1);

WeekSchedule.AppointmentTemplate = DataTemp;
CalendarGrid.Children.Add(WeekSchedule);
```

The expected results would be to be able to add the Rectange and Grid to the DataTemplate which would be added to the apppointmenttemplate then to the schedule.

This is basically a dummy code for testing, i would like to know if its possible to do it this way?

Thank you

Comment: Why aren't you doing this in XAML? Creating datatemplates in C# is a hassle.

Comment: Edit: Have been getting a black screen issue due to some older version of Windows when accessing a window on with the calendar is present.

Comment: And you think that by creating the DataTemplate in C#, you'll be able to fix that?

Comment: Setting the NavigationCacheMode to enabled for the page, solves the issue of the black screen, but gives a big performance degradation. The idea is to clear a maximum memory but keep the cache so that not to lose the performance by creating the calendar dynamically through code each time we access the screen

Answer (score 1):

Use below code snippet to resolve your issue. In below code we have used FrameworkElementFactory instead of FramWorkElement.

```
            DataTemplate appointmentTemplate = new DataTemplate();
            appointmentTemplate.DataType = typeof(ScheduleDaysAppointmentViewControl);
            FrameworkElementFactory grid = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
            grid.SetValue(Grid.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
            grid.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);


            FrameworkElementFactory rect = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Rectangle));
            rect.SetValue(Rectangle.FillProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White));
            rect.SetValue(Rectangle.StrokeProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black));
            rect.SetValue(Rectangle.StrokeThicknessProperty, 3d);

            grid.AppendChild(rect);
            appointmentTemplate.VisualTree = grid;
            schedule.AppointmentTemplate = appointmentTemplate;
```

And find sample for the same in below link.

Sample:http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SfSchedule_WPF983671020

Regards,
Magesh S